# Some help understanding Interface constraints (xcode)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

So I have a text view on a view Controller in xcode and i have constraints that keep it in the center of the screen.

But whenever i run the simulator, I only see about half the text view and the other half is off the screen. Am i just not understanding what constraints are used for? Or am I doing something wrong? How would I essentially keep it in the center of the screen no matter what device screen size is being used?

Comment: What constraints have you added?  You need to constrain both position and size. The simplest way may be to constrain the leading edge to the leading margin, and the trailing edge to the trailing margin or you can use a center constraint but then you will also need to constrain the width somehow. What exactly is the layout you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly center your Text View in the center of the ViewControler using AutoLayout constraints, ensure you are following the two essential configurations as below:

Storyboards in versions of Xcode before 7 had to match the screen size of the target device. This clearly isn’t possible with the “one storyboard to rule them all” approach, so with Xcode 7 the storyboard is given an abstract size instead.
The Use Size Classes option, found in the File Inspector, enables this new format for your project; select the storyboard, open the File Inspector and you’ll see the checkbox option as shown in image in link below:

[image: Image: Storyboard Size classes setting.]

Once you have ensured the setting 'Use Size classes' is selected as above, use Auto Layout constraints to center the Text View in the View Controller as per image in link below:
(If you need then select vertically in container option as well)

[image: Image: Auto layout center horizontally in container.]